# Selecting id and value where max occurs

Tags: mysql, select, max

I've solved one issue and ran into another. Basicaly i want to select question_id, answer and maximum number of occurences. I run my query from basic table that gathers questions and answers to them (question id represents question and answer represents answer from 0 to 5 that corresponds to other table but that doesn't matter).

```
**survey_result**
question_id
answer (int from 0 to 5)
```

Sample survey_result:

```
question_id answer
1           3
1           5
1           2
2           2
2           0
2           4
```

Here's the query, it's purpose is to check for every single question, which answer (from 0 to 5) occured the most.

```
select question_id, answer, max(occurence_number) FROM
(select question_id, answer, count(*) as occurence_number
from survey_result
group by question_id, answer
order by question_id asc, occurence_number desc) as results
GROUP BY question_id
```

So a **sub query** results in something like this:

```
question_id answer occurence_number
1           0      12
1           1      20
1           2      34
1           3      5
1           4      9
1           5      15
```

But main query results something like this:

```
question_id answer occurence_number
1           0      12
2           0      20
3           0      34
4           0      5
```

So the problem is that it always shows answer 0, and i want to get correct answer number.

Comment: It happens because MySQL (unlike other RDBMS) allows you to place columns in the `SELECT` list which are not also in the `GROUP BY`. That produces non-deterministic results for other columns.

Comment: Can you explain better what value you expect to get for the `answer`?

Comment: The query isn't quite right due to what @MichaelBerkowski just commented. Could you add some sample values and a desired result?

Comment: Still unclear. Can you provide test data and desired result?

Comment: Is your goal to get both the question and answer which had the greatest occurrence number?

Comment: What is the desired result in the case of a tie?

Comment: Ok to sum up problem: Every question has it's id. There are many occurences of same question. Every question has an answer from 0 to 5. I want to sum up all the answers for every question (q_id1 - 0, q_id1 - 1 etc.), and then for every question select the answer, that has the most occurences (and number of occurences as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly a bit redundant due to MySQL's lack of a `WITH` statement, but this should do what you want. In case of a tie, it will return the higher answer.

```
SELECT s1.question_id, MAX(s1.answer) answer, MAX(s1.c) occurrences
FROM
   (SELECT question_id, answer, COUNT(*) c 
    FROM survey_result GROUP BY question_id,answer) s1
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT question_id, answer, COUNT(*) c
    FROM survey_result GROUP BY question_id,answer) s2
  ON s1.question_id=s2.question_id
 AND s1.c < s2.c
WHERE s2.c IS NULL
GROUP BY question_id
```

[An SQLfiddle to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddb55/2).

Comment: Hey i do not want to select MAX of answer (answer number indicates answer value), these values are always from 0 to 5, so using max answer would always return 5

Comment: @Malyo It will get the correct answer, but if both answer 3 and 4 have 44 votes, it will pick 4 as the winner. If 3 gets 44 and 4 gets 42, it will, as you say, pick 3.

Comment: This works perfect. I'm still having troubles fully understanding the code, but it works, and i'm very thankful for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating it, try this:

```
select question_id, answer, count(*) as occurence_number
from survey_result
group by question_id, answer
```

Comment: That's not correct my friend. There are many occurences of answer for each id. I need to count them all, then for every question_id i need to select the answer and number of occurences, where number of occurences i maximum (for specific id)